# SpringMVC: ExceptionHandler fails to catch my custom exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

In my **main controller**, when the exception is thrown, I want it to be catched by the `ExceptionHandler` in my **error handling controller**, but that never happens. Instead, I am getting `Error 500`. I am suspecting the problem is in `@ResponseBody` annotation of my main controller. Any idea how to achieve wanted behavior?

Main controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/{person}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Person execute(@PathVariable(value = "person") String person) {

    if(person.isValid(person)) {
            return person;
    } else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Invalid person format.");
    }
}
```

Exception

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public ResourceNotFoundException() {
    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
        super(message, throwable);
    }

    public ResourceNotFoundException(Throwable throwable) {
        super(throwable);
    }
}
```

Error controller

```
private static final String ERROR_PAGE = "errors/error.jsp";

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
    public ModelAndView invalidApiCall(){
        return generateView(ERROR_404);
    }

    private ModelAndView generateView(String errorCode) {
        return new ModelAndView(ERROR_PAGE);

    }
```

My error view never gets generated (@ExceptionHandler never catches the exception). Instead I am getting error 500. Is there a way for ExceptionHandler to catch my exception?

Comment: share the error controller class full source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `@ControllerAdvice` annotation for the Error Controller. If it is already added, check whether the class' package is included in package scan.